# Can this be considered as proof? / Any better ways to prove this?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

I'm new to proof writing, so i started with an easy, soft problem: Here it is:

Prove that $ 3^{n} - 2 $ is odd $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} $.

How did i started:

Definition: A number is said even if he can be written as $2p, \forall p \in \mathbb{N}$. A number is said odd if he can be written as $2p \pm 1, \forall p \in \mathbb{N}$.

So:

Let $K = 3^n $.$K$ will be odd $\forall n$ (The product of two odd numbers is always an odd number) , so $K = 2p + 1$ for a $p \in \mathbb{N}$. Then the number $N = 3^n -2$ can be written as $2p+1-2$ which is $2p-1$, so $N$ is an odd number.

This is correct (i think), but my question is: Can this be accepted as a good proof? If not, what are the best (or most formal) ways to prove things like this? Thanks!

Comment: Modular arithmetic provides a shorter cleaner solution:  $3^n-2\equiv 1^n-0\equiv 1\pmod{2}$.  As for your proof, yes it is correct but could be formalized a bit more in your statement that $3^n$ is odd.  You correctly state that the product of two odd numbers is odd, but there is a logical step needed to continue this to the statement "the product of arbitrarily many odd numbers is odd" which can be accomplished by induction.  The fact that the product of arbitrarily many odd numbers is again odd is a trivial and wellknown fact, and so need not be included depending on your audience.

Comment: How do you know the product of two odd numbers is odd?  And what two odd numbers is $3^n$ the product of?  If you are going to basics to the degree you define even and odd you will have to prove these basics.

Comment: It depends entirely on what the accepted groundwork is. If you feel the need to actually define what even and odd mean then I figure you'll need to prove that the product of odds is odd and that $3^n$ is a product of two odds.  On the other hand, you probably *don't* need to define what odd and even is.  But then saying $3^n -2$ is odd as $3^n $ is odd and $2$ is even is probably not acceptable for the purpose of learning to write proofs.  Have you already proven odd x odd = odd? You'll need a statement that inductively that implies odd^n; n>0 is odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are definitely on the right track but I have some quibbles.

"Definition: A number is said even if he can be written as 2p,∀p∈N."

That should be either: "Definition: A number is said even if he can be written as 2p,for some $p \in \mathbb N$".  or "Definition: A number, $m$, is said even if $\exists p \in \mathbb N$ so that $m = 2p$."

What you wrote says the number can be written as $2p$ for *all* natural numbers.  That means the number *is* every possible even number *at the same time*.  $m =2$ and $m =4$ AND $m=20,456$ and... clearly impossible.

"Let $K=3^n$.K will be odd ∀n (The product of two odd numbers is always an odd number)"

If you claim it, you have to prove it. Add something to the effect that:

If $m = 2p + 1$ and $n = 2q+1$ then $m*n = (2p +1)(2q+1) = 4pq + 2p + 2q + 1 = 2(2pq + p + q) + 1$ and $m*n$ is odd.  Therefore the product of two odd numbers is odd.

Also you need to explain the $3^n$ *is* the product of two odd numbers.  Which two?

Do something like:

$3 = 2*1 + 1$ is odd.  So $3*3$ is odd. If we know $3^{k}$ is odd, we can conclude that $3^{k+1} = 3^{k}*3$ is odd.  So inductively $3^n$ is odd for all $n\ge 1$.

Then the rest of your proof is good.

=====

Yes, I am being *very* *very* picky.  But in general your idea about proof writing is good.

Comment: That was the kind of answer i was looking for! Thanks a lot!